# How to $compile an AngularJS template using a newly created scope?

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a pop-up modal that I want to have the capabilities of being updated dynamically using a newly created `$scope`. I want to do something like this:

```
var myNewScope = $scope.$new();
myNewScope.name = 'Jack';

ModalService.open('Hello, {{ name }}', myNewScope);
```

Then in my `ModalService.open` method I want to compile that string with the given scope like this

```
// ... other service stuff

service.open = function(template, scope){
    var compiledText = $compile(template)(scope);
    // I want compiledText = 'Hello, Jack'
}
```

Comment: Oh I just realized that it does work if I wrap my template in an actual DOM element like `ModalService.open('<h1>Hello, {{ name }}</h1>')`.. why does it NEED to be like this? What if I just want the string without the actual element?

Comment: It's unclear what you want. Based on the question and your own answer it seems you want `$interpolate`. On the other hand "being updated dynamically" doesn't apply to your answer. And I'm wondering why you want to interpolate the text yourself anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Welp... I don't think angular has a built in way to do this.. so I just built my own version.

```
app.controller('TestController', function($scope, $compile){

  var scope = $scope.$new();
  scope.percentage = {Value:55};
  scope.name = 'Jack';

  var msg = 'We are at {{ percentage.Value }}% done, {{ name }}.. {{ 4/3 }}';

  var element = msg.replace(/{{\s*([a-zA-Z0-9+-/*//\s.]*)\s*}}/g, function($0, $1){
    return scope.$eval($1);
  } );

  console.log(element); // prints 'We are at 55% done, Jack.. 1.3333333333333333' 
});
```

This seems to be working pretty well