# AngularJS $compile

Tags: angularjs

The below functions works well.

```
var el = angular.element('<div>{{ name }}</div>');
elem.append(el);
$compile(el)(scope);
```

but why does this not work?

```
var el = angular.element('<div>{{ name }}</div>');
elem.append(el);
$compile(el)({name:'Fred'});
```

Isn't scope just an object w/name-value pairs?

RESOLUTION:
[How to $compile an AngularJS template using a newly created scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642535/how-to-compile-an-angularjs-template-using-a-newly-created-scope)

or resolution in code format

```
    var elS = angular.element($templateCache.get('tmpl/x.html')[1]);
    var linkFn = $compile(elS);

    var newScope = scope.$new();
    newScope.s = scope.sCtrl.s;

    var content = linkFn(newScope);
    el.append(content);
```

Comment: The $compile service is the service to use for compilation. Invoking $compile against markup will produce a function you can use to bind the markup against a particular scope (what Angular calls a linking function). After linking, you’ll have DOM elements you can place into the browser.

Comment: Thank you Ved, I understand this, but how do I create my own scope? I'm not sure why the object literal I created earlier isn't working when I call the linking function above.

Comment: Check this link: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/07/using-compile-in-angular.aspx

Comment: This resolved my issue. Thanks for your input Ved.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642535/how-to-compile-an-angularjs-template-using-a-newly-created-scope

Answer (score 0):

In angular you write template markup html, which needs to be compiled first before it can be rendered in the browser. $compile converts the template html to DOM html.
Template Html markup usually has variables that are linkable from their originally definition in scope. Those can be linked using $compile. As a end result compile transforms the markup can be rendered in the browser.